# Loop over JSON with Handlebars JS and Ember JS

Tags: json, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am learning Ember JS and Handlebars JS so I am very new to this. I am having an issue trying to loop through the following JSON.

Here is my JSON:

```
{
    "sgt_rules": {
        "app_tags": {},
        "city": [],
        "consumer_tags": [],
        "device_tags": {
            "os": [
                "ios"
            ]
        },
        "participation": null,
        "registration": null
     }
}
```

This is my handlebars template:

```
<h2>{{controllers.segment.sgt_name}}</h2>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="pull">
  <ul>
    <li>{{getsegmentrules}}</li>
  </ul>

</script>
```

The ember helper function in case I need to modify it:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var controller = Ember.Controller.extend({
   needs: ['segment'],
   getsegmentrules: function () {

      var model = this.get('content').get('sgt_rules');

   }.property()});


export default controller;
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="pull">
<ul>
 <li>{{controllers.segment.sgt_rules}}</li>
 {{#each segment in controllers.segment.sgt_rules}}
      <li>App Tags: {{segment.app_tags}} <br /> City: {{segment.city}} <br />
          Consumer Tags: {{segment.consumer_tags}} <br /> Device Tags: {{segment.device_tags}} <br />
          Participation: {{segment.participation}} <br /> Registration: {{segment.registration}} <br />
        <ul>
          {{#each obj in segment.device_tags}}
            <li>{{obj.os}}</li>
          {{/each}}
          </ul>
       </li>
 {{/each}}
</ul>
</script>
```

What am I missing here? Do I need to write any helper function as well?

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't you return a value here?

```
   getsegmentrules: function () {
      var model = this.get('content').get('sgt_rules');
      return model;
   }.property()});
```

Also where are you setting the JSON data?

Comment: By `controllers.segment.sgt_rules` from Handlebars I already get the JSON.